# check class child class is available or not jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="formSortable ui-sortable">
    <div id="formItem_c_firstName" class="formItem leftLabel selected">
        <label class="varcharIcon">First Name</label>
        <div class="formInputBox">
            <input type="text" id="Name" >
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

formSortable class child class formItem having **selected** class or not 
my jquery is

```
if ($('.formSortable').find('formItem').hasClass('selected')) {
                   alert("hi");
               }
```

Comment: Typo missing `.` in `.find('formItem')`

Comment: Wow!!! what a **oscar wining** typo. Rain of answers.....^^.

Comment: someone has upvoted this question .

Comment: @AmitKumar Grr... i am searching for that fellow..!

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
if( $('.formSortable').find('.formItem.selected').length > 0 ) {
    alert( 'hi' );
}
```

Or this:

```
$('.formSortable').find('.formItem.selected').length == 0 || alert( 'hi' );
```

Should work fine.

But if per the title you really meant **child of '.formSortable'** then use `.children()` instead of `.find()`:

```
if( $('.formSortable').children('.formItem.selected').length > 0 ) {
    alert( 'hi' );
}
```

Or:

```
$('.formSortable').children('.formItem.selected').length == 0 || alert( 'hi' );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('.formSortable').find('.formItem').hasClass('selected')) {
                   alert("hi");
               }
```

you have missed the **.** before formitem .

Answer (score 3):

You missed a class selector (.) in `formitem`

Answer (score 2):

you missed `dot` prefix for class `formItem`

```
if ($('.formSortable').find('.formItem').hasClass('selected')) {
   alert("hi");
}
```

or another possibility find with `.length` in jquery

```
if ($('.formSortable').find('.formItem.selected').length) {
   alert("hi");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KEZY6/)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a dot in `find('formItem')`:

```
if ($('.formSortable').find('.formItem').hasClass('selected')) {
    alert("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `find('.formItem')` - `.` class selector  and not `find('formItem')`.

```
if ($('.formSortable').find('.formItem').hasClass('selected')) {
     alert("hi");
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BjQ7Q/)**

Answer (score 2):

missed class selector  `'.formItem'`

```
if ($('.formSortable').find('.formItem').hasClass('selected')) {
                   alert("hi");
               }
```